# In memory storage on nodejs server

Tags: node.js, caching, express, memcached

There seem to be quite a few promising packages with no clear suggestions on which is the fastest,scalable and which is more memory efficient.

1. npm install [memoizee](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memoizee)
2. npm install [memcached](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memcached)
3. [lru-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lru-cache)
4. npm install [memory-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memory-cache)
5. npm install [node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache)

Any reliable sources of information/personal experience with these would help.
So the basic usage is for simple key:value store.
Just need to know if the underlying architecture of these different stores is similar/different and if different then which would be scalable.

[Also which of these is used by [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) to implement the **MemoryStore**.]

Comment: You're kind of asking something akin to "which database is best"?  In reality, it's a complicated question that depends upon a series of requirements and tradeoffs and, in some cases, preferred programming styles.  In many cases, you can simply use a Javascript object to store things in memory too without getting any sort of external package/library.  it all depends upon your requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependencies for express-session are right on Github in its [package.json](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/package.json).  I don't see any of your listed storage mechanisms.

Then, if you look at the code for the `MemoryStore` object [here](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/session/memory.js), you can see that it's just using a Javascript object to store a list of sessions indexed by `sessionId`.

Comment: thanks for the information,ive edited the question a bit.Can you please tell which of the 5 npm packages is best for in memory storage on the nodejs server.Or is there some other better package?

Answer (score 3):

"Which one is better" depends on your requirements such as traffic volume, how much you want to store in-memory cache etc.

When you select an in-memory store, keep in mind node.js is single-threaded and for-loops are blocking codes. If you look at the source for most of these packages such as node-cache, they all have for-loops, iterating through all your cached items for TTL check. So if you store 10000 objects, your app is going to be blocked until 10k iteration is completed. So beware of your choice.

Comment: So the basic usage is for simple key:value store.I just need to know if the underlying architecture of these different stores is similar/different and if different then which would be scalable.

Comment: They are mostly similar except for memcached which allows you to setup clusters and scale. I would not recommend rest of packages in your list for storing large number of items.