# Does Node.js or another JS server tech support native shared memory between requests without serialization?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shared-memory

When I search for node.js shared memory, I find only third party solutions that rely on inter-process communication, OS memory mapped files, third party caching servers, and/or string serialization.  These are less efficient methods compared to accessing native objects directly inside the same process.

To clarify some more, I'd prefer shared memory that works this way:

- node.js would have some kind of global object scope that every
  request can see.
- The size of the global scope would only be limited by system memory
  size.
- Node would need to provide "named locks" or some other method of
  locking. (I think node.js doesn't need this unless you use workers)
- The solution must be written in pure Javascript (no "C" add-on)
- There is no serialization of the stored object.

I'm primarily a ColdFusion/CFML developer.  All I have to do is this to share native objects between requests.

application.myVar={ complex: "object", arr:["anything", "i", "want"] };

I already wrote an application that stores massive lookup tables, partial html, and more in memory using ColdFusion. There is no I/O or interprocess communication for most requests.  Can this be done in node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js is already a single threaded server, so any request would be handled within the same scope.

And there are already libs just for that: [In memory storage on nodejs server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304740/in-memory-storage-on-nodejs-server)

If you need to scale you can move on to some other store later on (redis, mongodb etc).